Set-theoretic difference of two varieties is generated by the saturation of the ideal
I want to show that $\overline{V(I)/V(J)}=V(I:J^\infty)$. I'm trying to generalise from this answer, which assumes that the ideals are radical.
One way round, the argument seems largely the same: $f\in (I:J^\infty)\implies$ for any $g\in J$, we have an $n$ such that $I\ni fg^n\implies fg^n(x)=0 \forall x\in V(I)/V(J)$. But since $x\notin V(J), g(x)\neq 0$ for some $g\in J\implies g^n(x)\neq 0$, which forces $f(x)=0\implies f\in \mathbb{I}[V(I)/V(J)]$.
As for the other way round: Well, $f(x)=0$ on $V(I)/V(J)\implies$ for all $g\in J, fg(x)=0\forall x\in V(I)\implies$ (by the Nullstellensatz) $(fg)^n\in I\implies f^n\in (I:J^\infty).$ But the saturation of an ideal is not radical in general, so this does not allow us to conclude $f\in (I:J^\infty)$. What is missing?

Well, $V(I:J^\infty)=V(\sqrt{(I:J^\infty)})$, so why is $f\in \sqrt{(I:J^\infty)}$ but $f\notin (I:J^\infty)$ a problem?

Oh. Is it true in general that $V(I)=V(\sqrt{I})$? Maybe because $f^n(x)=0\iff f(x)=0$, since polynomial rings are integral domains?

Yes, $V(I)=V(\sqrt{I})$ as sets for any ideal $I$ of any ring. The explanation depends on your level - if you are working with schemes, this is the fact that a prime ideal contains $I$ iff it contains $\sqrt{I}$; if you are working with "classical varieties" then this is the fact that if $f^n$ evaluates to $0$ at a point $x$, then $f$ must also evaluate to $0$ at $x$ since the evaluation happens inside the base field $k$.

If that resolves your issues, please let me know and I'll write it down as an answer. If not, please edit your post to clarify what's still at issue here.

Yes, it does-thanks.

As per discussion in the comments, we have $V(I:J^\infty) = V(\sqrt{(I:J^\infty)})$, so saying that $f^n\in (I:J^\infty)$ is not an issue, and we can still conclude that $\overline{V(I)\setminus V(J)} = V(I:J^\infty)$ as sets. The underlying claim that makes this true is that $V(I)=V(\sqrt{I})$ as sets - in the case of schemes, this follows because a prime ideal contains $I$ iff it contains $\sqrt{I}$; in the case of classical varieties, this follows since $f(x)=0$ iff $f(x)^n=0$, since evaluation happens inside the base field $k$ (which has no nilpotents).
